# How do I get Spiritomb on Pokémon Platinum

Tags: pokemon-fourth-generation

I have been having trouble finding out how to find Spiritomb. I know how to get the Odd Keystone but I don't understand what the guy says to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You place the [Odd Keystone](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Odd_Keystone) at the [Hallowed Tower](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Hallowed_Tower). You then talk to 32 other players in the [Underground](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/The_Underground). After that, Spiritomb should appear on your next visit to the Hallowed Tower.

Answer (score 1):

It does not have to be 32 seperate players, one player can repeatedly go up and down, and you can talk to him/her each time 32 times.